# How to perform complex operations (loops) within a buffered reader?

Tags: java, parsing, loops, bufferedreader

I am trying to initialize class fields by reading data from a text file. An example text file would look like this:

```
Movies
Lord of the Rings: 180
Fight Club: 120
Theaters
A:100
B:50
C:200
Shows
1,1,960
1,1,1080
1,1,1200
1,3,1020
1,3,1140
2,2,990
2,2,1210
Prices
Adult:10
Child:7
Senior:8
End
```

The following is my code which returns an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

In this code I am trying to parse the lines under "Movies" category of the file into a class field which is an array list of Movies. A

Movie has the fields Name(String) and Length(String). I attempt this by splitting the line using the delmiter ":" in the line (to split the movie name and length number).

```
    public static void inititializeFromFile(String fileName) 
            throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if(line.equals("Movies")) {

                while (!(line.equals("Theaters"))) {
                    String currentline = line;
                    String[] parts = currentline.split(":");
                    String part1 = parts[0]; 
                    String part2 = parts[1]; 
                    movies.add(new Movie(part1, part2));
                }
            }
            if(line.equals("Shows")) {
                // do something
            }
            if(line.equals("Prices")) {
                // do something
            }
            if(line.equals("Theaters")) {
                // do something
            }
            if(line.equals("...")) {
                // do something
            }
            else if(line.contains(":")) {
                //do something
            }
            else if(line.equals("End")) {
                // do something
            }
            else {
                // anything else
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I am new to BufferedReaders so any input or suggestions on a better approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach your  2nd while loop under the Movies if test your line still is equal to Movies. You arent reading any more lines inside your if test. Your are actually attempting to do `"Movies".split(":")[1];` and this is giving you your index out of bounds.

You should be reading more lines in after you reach the Movies string inside your 2nd while loop.

```
if(line.equals("Movies")) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("Theaters")) {
        String currentline = line;
        String[] parts = currentline.split(":");
        String part1 = parts[0]; 
        String part2 = parts[1]; 
        movies.add(new Movie(part1, part2));
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Many times when working with files especially if you didnt write them you can have trailing spaces, extra new lines and all sorts of discrepancies. This is why I recommended you use `System.out.println` to observe your program flow easily and quickly. Here is how I would set it up for this area

```
if(line.equals("Movies")) {
    System.out.println("Hit Movies");
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("Theaters")) {
       System.out.println("pasing ("+line+")");
        String currentline = line;
        String[] parts = currentline.split(":");
        String part1 = parts[0]; 
        String part2 = parts[1]; 
        movies.add(new Movie(part1, part2));
    }
    System.out.println("Finished Movies");
}
```

As you can see I put parentheses around the line output `"pasing ("+line+")"`. This gets to my point of discrepancies. There is likely a trailing space on the Theaters line. You are possibly comparing

`"Theaters ".equals("Theaters")`.

You can solve this by doing the following: `!line.trim().equals("Theaters")`.

Trailing spaces, case sensitivity, hidden ASCII characters are all gotchas in the parsing world.

Comment: @user3063864 the same as you were doing in your first loop. reader.readLine(). You then assign that to the line variable and see if it is null (End of File).

Comment: I see. I added it to my code and the IndexOutOfBounds is no longer occurring, but now I am getting a NullPounterException from the line "
                    movies.add(new Movie(part1, part2));". Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @user3063864 If the last stack on the heap was in fact that line then movies = null. I would highly recommend you put a bunch of System.out.println in your loops to see whats going on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I use the system out prints and it seems that the loop doesn't stop once it hits "Theaters". For example, it splits and returns the move strings perfectly, but then it tries to do the same for "Theaters" and it can't so it returns null. I don't see why it would given the parameters of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

```
        if(line.equals("Movies")) {

            while (!(line.equals("Theaters"))) {
                String currentline = line;
                String[] parts = currentline.split(":");
                String part1 = parts[0]; 
                String part2 = parts[1]; 
                movies.add(new Movie(part1, part2));
            }
        }
```

The first line of code, reads a line. The second line, reads nothing. Third line nothing. Fourth line, `currentLine = line` makes `currentLine = Movie` because you haven't read any line after that. So you try and split `Movies` with `:` which does not exist so you one have index 0 to work with. index 1 is out of bounds.

The inside loop should also read a line

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !(line.equals("Theaters"))) {
```